# How can I use a preprocessor macro in a method declaration?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm shifting between Xcode 6 and 7 quite frequently, and want a way to avoid build warnings like this one.

> Conflicting return type in implementation of
>   'supportedInterfaceOrientations': 'UIInterfaceOrientationMask' (aka
>   'enum UIInterfaceOrientationMask') vs 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned
>   long')

I can't seem to use a type that will satisfy both versions of Xcode simultaneously. So I was going to implement a preprocessor macro which had different values depending on the value of __IPHONE_9_0.

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_9_0
#define CompatibilityUserInterfaceMask  UIInterfaceOrientationMask
#else
#define CompatibilityUserInterfaceMask  NSUInteger
#endif
```

When I try and implement this though I get a build error.

```
- (CompatibilityUserInterfaceMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations { ... }
```

Is this possible, or does anyone have other ideas to achieve the same outcome?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell your macro should just work, but if you want a slightly different approach (arguably uglier):

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < 90000  
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations  
#else  
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations  
#endif
```